# Can I call a Google cloud function from Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Can I call a Google cloud function from Firebase hosting?? I have a Google cloud function with memory store and I have others APIs in cloud run. These APIs in cloud run are to be called from Firebase hosting because I want to have the same base URL client. Is it possible to call from Firebase hosting the Google cloud function written in python ?

Comment: What do you mean by "from Firebase Hosting"?  Firebase Hosting doesn't run any code.  It just serves static web assets.  You can invoke a Cloud Function HTTP trigger from almost anywhere in the world.  Is there some part of this you're having trouble with in particular?

Comment: @DougStevenson Serve dynamic content with Firebase hosting. I can call cloud run APIs o Firebase Cloud Functions, but can I call HTTP Google Cloud Functions?